# How do nuclear physicists know for certain if a very short-lived nucleus has been formed (a new isotope)?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chemistry, nucleosynthesis

Some very short-lived nuclides (sometimes called 'resonances') are nevertheless considered to have actually existed, if only very very briefly....

How do nuclear physicists know the isotope actually existed at all?

Is there some particle(s) released by the extremely ephemeral nucleus that otherwise would not have been released?

Comment: Do you have a particular example in mind? In a scattering experiment, those resonances show up as large cross sections to do 'something', the exact thing(s) being a question of the resonant state. For example, the large cross section of D-T fusion was explained through a resonance with He-5.